# Frappe-Gantt - is not a constructor

Tags: angular

I have the following imports in my constructor:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import * as Gantt from './frappe-gantt.js';
```

In my `ngOnInit()` I have a

```
var gantt = new Gantt.default(`#${this.id}`, this.tasks, { ... })
```

This throws me the following error:

> _frappe_gantt_frappe_gantt_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a is not a constructor

Got any idea about this?

EDIT:
Printing `console.log(Gantt)` starting the component returns me `{}`

My `frappe-gantt.js` is as:

```
var Gantt = (function () {
    'use strict';
     ...
    }
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you upload your ts code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are working with "legacy" code that doesn't actually export anything and instead executes an IIFE, probably assigning something to global variable or `window`. Try the following import instead:

```
import './frappe-gantt.js';
```

In documentation for [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) this is described as "Import a module for its side effects only". This does assume that `Gantt` is being exposed as a global variable.

That being said, if you have access to this file, you probably should turn it into an actual TypeScript file and exporting `Gantt` as you would with any other module in your Angular project.

Hopefully that helps!